# What is *energy* in the context of linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, definition

I have heard and read the term *energy* in the context of LA a few times now. e.g:

> The algorithm is based on the geometrical observations that the word
>   embeddings (across all representations such as Glove, word2vec etc.)
>   have a large mean vector and most of their **energy** (after subtracting the mean
>   vector) is located in a subspace of about 8 dimensions.

I am having a hard time finding explanation on this energy concept however. Searching for *subspace energy* will give you Star Trek related results for example :D
Searching for *linear algebra energy* will result in things like *What is the importance of linear algebra in renewable energy engineering?*

So, can you explain to me what *energy* in LA is and how I can find material on it?

Comment: Are you sure that energy is due to the linear algebra context and not the NLP/ML context? It looks like the article is trying to use energy to represent some sort of weighting.

Comment: @KitterCatter Yes, I heard it in a pure math lecture by Gilbert Strang once too, but with no further explanation.

Comment: People sometimes use the word "energy" fairly loosely in settings like this. I see no connection (or at most, only a very loose connection) with the physical concept of energy. They could instead just say that there exists a subspace $W$ of dimension 8 such that for each word embedding vector $w$ the vector $v = w - \mu$ belongs approximately to $W$. (In other words, the residual $v - \text{proj}_W(v)$ is small.) Here $\mu$ is the mean of the word embedding vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can reasonably be inferred from your quote that the phrasing *have most of one's energy in subspace $V$* is an empiric way to say that a vector "almost lies in" $V$.

There are different ways you can measure that. For instance, in a Euclidean space, the ratio $$\frac{\|\text{orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $V$}\|}{\|v\|}$$ somewhat tells you the "proportion" of $v$ that lies in $V$.

A practical framework where this could occur is signal analysis, where the energy of a signal is the sum of squares of its Fourier components.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that "energy" here means the squared magnitude of a vector:

$$E(\mathbf{x}) = \|\mathbf{x}\|^2.$$

This would be a generalization of what "energy" means for an analog signal (such as a sound wave, or an electric signal traveling through a long transmission line), which is the integral of the square of the analog signal:

$$E(f) = \|f\|^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ dx.$$

The quoted paragraph is describing a collection $\mathbf{w}$ of vectors and stating that "most of their energy (after subtracting the mean vector) is located in a subspace of about 8 dimensions," meaning that $\mathbf{w}$ can be written as $\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} + \mathbf{z},$ where

- $\mathbf{x}$ is "the mean vector,"
- $\mathbf{y}$ is the component of $\mathbf{w}$ "after subtracting the mean vector" which is found in a subspace of about 8 dimensions,
- $\mathbf{z}$ is the remainder,
- $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{y}$, and $\mathbf{z}$ are pairwise orthogonal,
- as a result of the above point, $E(\mathbf{w}) = E(\mathbf{x}) + E(\mathbf{y}) + E(\mathbf{z}),$ and
- $E(\mathbf{y})$ is much greater than $E(\mathbf{z})$.